# Databricks SQL PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT name FROM bop WHERE Id='1') IS NOT NULL
      AND (SELECT name FROM bop WHERE Id='7') IS NOT NULL
    THEN name
    ELSE null
    END as result
FROM bop
```

I am getting this error for the third line (WHEN (SELECT ...):

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '('.(line 3, pos 9)

== SQL ==
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT name FROM bop WHERE Id='1') IS NOT NULL
---------^^^
      AND (SELECT name FROM bop WHERE Id='7') IS NOT NULL
    THEN name
    ELSE null
    END as result
FROM bop
```

I have tried removing the parentheses and I have validated the column names and table name are all correct. I have also tried:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN name IS NOT NULL WHERE Id in ('1', '7')
    THEN name
    ELSE null
    END as result
FROM bop
```

But I get the same error:

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'answer_option_name'.(line 3, pos 9)

== SQL ==
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN name IS NOT NULL WHERE Id in ('1', '7')
---------^^^
    THEN name
    ELSE null
    END as result
FROM bop
```

Here is some data for table bop:

| name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| null | 1 |
| john | 1 |
| stacy | 5 |
| jose | 6 |
| carrie | 6 |
| null | 7 |

and my desired output would be: john

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result? Using a SELECT like that in a CASE statement is generally only valid for scalar subqueries

Comment: We need to see your desired output.

Comment: In the CASE you could change WHEN name IS NOT NULL WHERE Id in ('1', '7') to WHEN name IS NOT NULL AND Id in ('1', '7'). But whether that's valid all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have provided sample data and desired output

Comment: Your CASE statement is also missing an "END"

Comment: adding in end did not resolve error, I updated post to include END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this counts as an answer, but it's easier to keep the formatting readable in an answer.

This will get you a record that has "John"

```
SELECT name
  FROM bop
 WHERE name is not null
   AND id in ('1','7') -- is this really a string datatype?
```

If you don't want filtering, reflect that in your expected output sample. But just to show the syntax

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN name is not null
             AND id in ('1','7') THEN name
            ELSE null -- ELSE isn't strictly necessary.
                      -- but I do it to signal that it was intentional
                      -- and not a miss.
        END as conditional_name
  FROM bop
```